# Find Only 1st Level XPath Children

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<div>
 <div>
  <span>test1</span>
 </div>
 <span>test2</span>
 <span>test3</span>
 <span>test4</span>
  <div>
    <span>test5</span>
  </div>
 <span>test6</span>
</div>
```

How can I select all span elements that are direct descendants of the 1st div. (Elements with innerText test2, test3, test4, test6) ?

Comment: Do you mean you need nodes with only single `id` attribute value?

Comment: Find outer-most divs and return the children div: `//div[not(ancestor::div)]/div`

Comment: @Andersson No, disregard the id. I have included id's just to better describe the issue. I need to select only the children divs and not the children's children. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @StephanieSafflower, just try `//div[@id="main"]/div` instead of `//div[@id="main"]//div`

Comment: `/div[not(div)]`

Comment: Your second example is easier since node names are different. In the first case, I don't think you can remove from the result the descendant divs since XPath it's a query language not a manipulation one.

Comment: You are right, but I have edited my question because I realized it wasn't reflecting the issue I was having. So what if the CCC on line 7 is a descendant of another AAA element?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to remove the `<div>`s if they are not relevant. Just put a single relevant example (perhaps using the XML you are actually working on). That will help much more than these contrived examples with invalid XML (the second bit).

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will get you want

`'//span[not(parent::div[parent::div])]'`

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//span[not(parent::div[parent::div])]' test.html | sed -re 's%(</[^>]+>)%\1\n%g'                                                                                 
<span>test2</span>                                                                                                                                                                                                
<span>test3</span>                                                                                                                                                                                                
<span>test4</span>                                                                                                                                                                                                
<span>test6</span>
```